# Using Python Subprocess to Run Charles Headless - Passing in Commands

Tags: python, subprocess, charles-proxy

I'm trying to utilize Charles Proxy's web interface feature that allows you to run Charles in headless mode and control Charles using curl commands to http://control.charles.

In terminal, when I run the following commands, I get my desired output:

```
Charles -headless &
curl -v -x <MY IP ADDRESS HERE> http://control.charles/session/start
curl -o session.chls <MY IP ADDRESS HERE> http://control.charles/session/download
```

I'm trying to reproduce these commands in Python using subprocess. Initially, I tried opening 3 different subprocesses for each of the commands above, only realizing that they all need to be within the same session.

Here's my implementation, but I'm not getting any output:

```
charles_init = subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

charles_init.stdin.write(b"Charles -headless")

charles_init.stdin.write(b"curl -v -x <MY IP ADDRESS HERE> http://control.charles/session/start")

charles_init.stdin.write(b"curl -o session.chls <MY IP ADDRESS HERE> http://control.charles/session/download")
```

Is the "&" in "Charles -headless &" relevant here? To my understanding, that "&" allows Charles to run in the background within a shell. Do I need to set shell=True when initially opening the subprocess?

If so, how do I avoid the security risks associated with shell=True?

Comment: If you are the only one that controls the input to the shell it is no a security risk, if user input go there it is.

Answer (score 0):

The `Charles -headless` does not return (so you were running it with `&` in original shell command), so you will need to use `&` to run it in the background in your Python snippet.

Since your subprocess is already launching a shell (the `/bin/bash` command), the `shell=True` option is irrelevant.

However, I believe the best way is to run each command as its own subprocess. E.g.:

```py
charles = subprocess.Popen(['Charles', '-headless'])  # In background already!
subprocess.run(['curl', '-v', '-x', '<MY IP ADDRESS HERE>', 'http://control.charles/session/start'])
subprocess.run(['curl', '-o', 'session.chls', '<MY IP ADDRESS HERE>', 'http://control.charles/session/download'])
# When done...
charles.kill()
charles.wait()
```